# Issue with updating innerHMTL with javascript prompt on load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to update the  tag with id = "content" with prompted info. For some reason the window.onload function isn't working. I've tried moving the  around to no success. Apparently the div is null but i'm not sure how to remedy this. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Exercise 3</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>User Information:</strong></p>
        <div id=”content”>...</div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function promptFunc() {
                let text; 
                let name = prompt("What is your full name?", "Name");
                let age = prompt("How old are you?", "Age");
                if (name == null || age == null || name == "" || age ==""){
                  text = "User did not enter information";
                }else {
                    text = "Hi, my name is "+name+" and i'm "+age+" years old.";
                }
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
            }

            window.onload=function(){
                promptFunc();
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')",`

Comment: You have the wrong type of quotes around your id `”content”` you can see they are slanted. Needs to be straight `<div id="content">...</div>`

Comment: If you are not using an IDE to code. I would recommend you start using one so you do not get the wrong quotes. VSCode is free and there are plenty of others out there.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Be careful with your edits, you fixed the bug.

Comment: That was a mistake, apologies

Comment: Thanks to all! Yeah I copied part of the code from a document, and my eyes didn't pick up the nuance! I use VScode, but I should set it up such that It runs the html through chrome so I can debug through console...

Comment: Apologies for the stupid error...

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has a mistake in **”content”** quotes. you have given the wrong quotes in **div id="content">**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Exercise 3</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>User Information:</strong></p>
        <div id="content">...</div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function promptFunc() {
                let text; 
                let name = prompt("What is your full name?", "Name");
                let age = prompt("How old are you?", "Age");
                if (name == null || age == null || name == "" || age ==""){
                  text = "User did not enter information";
                }else {
                    text = `Hi, my name is ${name} and i'm ${age} years old.`;
                }
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
            }

             window.onload=function(){
                promptFunc();
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Exercise 3</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <p><strong>User Information:</strong></p>
    <div id="content">...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function promptFunc() {
            let text;
            let name = prompt("What is your full name?", "Name");
            let age = prompt("How old are you?", "Age");
            if (name == null || age == null || name == "" || age == "") {
                text = "User did not enter information";
            } else {
                text = "Hi, my name is " + name + " and i'm " + age + " years old.";
            }
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            promptFunc();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Use the double quotation("") in id="content"